# HP Loadrunner Analysis can't open .lrr file

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I cannot open a .lrr file with my laptop and I see the below error log message:

> Error: "Parse command line error: The INSERT INTO statement contains
>   the following unknown field name 'F4'Make sure you have typed the name
>   correctly, and try the operation again"

This error message is not seen when :

- I open the same .lrr with another pc
- I open the .lra file of same result

Another information is about the result format that is in "Access 2000". I have supposed that issue is related to something I have installed/updated directly in Windows. But no uninstall/re-install procedure bring me to solution (I have also reinstalled LR but nothing change).

Vincenzo

Comment: This is highly due to regional configuration is not set properly. 

Open Control Panel.
Go to Region and Language
Make sure you setup 

Decimal Symbol as , (comma)
Digit Grouping Symbol as . (dot)
List Separator as ; (semicolon)

Apply the changes and open LR Analysis file.

Let me know if this works for you. :)

Comment: Thanks @NaveenKumarNamachivayam! 
It resolves mine problem!

Comment: Can you please accept my answer :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is highly due to regional configuration is not set properly in your system. Follow the steps below.

1. Open **Control Panel**.
2. Go to **Region and Language**
3. Make sure you setup below particulars:

   Decimal Symbol as **,** (comma)

   Digit Grouping Symbol as **.** (dot)

   List Separator as **;** (semicolon)
4. Apply the changes and open LR Analysis file.